# "Parameterization", "Change of Variables", "Transformation", "Change of Coordinates": What's the Difference?

Tags: vector-analysis, transformation, parametric, parametrization, change-of-variable

What is the difference between **parameterization** and **change of variables**? How do I know when I'm doing one or the other? Also, under which one of these does "transformations" and "change of coordinates" fall?

For instance, I've recently been working on the following problem:

> The function $u(x,y)$ satisfies $u_y + u_x = 0$ in $x > 0$, $y > 0$ together with the initial condition $u(x, 0) = \sin(x)$, $x > 0$ and the boundary condition $u(0, y) = \sin(y)$, $y > 0$. Determine the values of $u$ in the whole quarter plane $x > 0$, $y > 0$.

Which requires us to change from $(x(s), y(s))$ to $(x(s, \tau), y(s, \tau))$, as follows:

$$x(s) = s + C_1(\tau)$$
$$y(s) = s + C_2(\tau)$$

$$x(0) = \tau$$
$$\therefore C_1(\tau) = \tau$$

$$y(0) = 0$$
$$\therefore C_2(\tau) = 0$$

Therefore, we have

$$x(s, \tau) = s + \tau$$
$$y(s, \tau) = s$$

Thank you for any help you can provide in making this clear.

Comment: IMO are more or less the same... different terminology may depends on context.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You mean they're all about the same? So we would be correct to call the example I gave any of the 4?

Comment: You can see [Change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **parametrize** a set $S$ is to write it as $$S=\{f(s)\mid s\in D\}$$ where $D$ is some domain where the parameter $s$ lives (it can be of any kind, but more often than not it is a $k$-tuple of real numbers).

Now if you start from a set endowed with a parametrization, you can change the parametrization by applying a bijection $\varphi: D'\to D$, resulting in 
$$S=\{f(\varphi(t))\mid t\in D'\}$$
This would be called a **change of variables** in general, but in the particular case where $D$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, you think of a parameter as an $n$-tuple of coordinates, and such a change of variables would then be called a **change of coordinates**.

For the last one, **transformation**, this can mean many things in many contexts, so you would have to make the question more precise.

---

Note that replacing $f(s), s\in D$ with $f(\varphi(t)), t\in D'$ is a change of variable in many contexts, not only when there is an underlying parametrization. $f$ can be an unknown function occurring in a differential equation for instance. In most contexts, there would be additional requirements on $\varphi$, not only being a bijection. It would need to respect a structure of some sort: be a diffeomorphism, linear, etc.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for that. So what would my example be?

Comment: @handler'shandle Your example looks like a change of variables, but it is hard to tell given we don't know what you mean by $x(s)$ in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I love questions about notation and terminology. Let's begin with parametrization *vs.* change of variable.

If we have a curve $\Gamma$ (which we can think of as a $1$-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an orientation defined), we call any function $\alpha\space\colon I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies $\alpha(I)=\Gamma$ a parametrization of the curve. Usually, you will want that parametrization to be one-to-one (injective).

Any other injective function $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ will be another parametrization of $\Gamma$, and as they are both injective, there will always exist a bijection – a *change of variable* of a function that represents a parametrization, which we call *reparametrization* – that takes you from one to the other and vice versa. So, for example: if you're computing line integrals, reparametrizing the curve in which you are integrating will be the same as performing a change of variable on the Riemann integral you have to compute to do the line integral.

The words variable and parameter are similae. We would say that the parameter $t$ of your parametric curve $\vec{\alpha}(t)$ is the independent variable of the function $\vec{r}=\vec{\alpha}(t)$.

You usually talk about parameters when parametrizing manifolds, and you talk about variables when you have any sort of function, specially in summations, integrals and stuff like that. So, if you have a function $f\colon\space\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, you would would say that you have $n$ independent variables $(x^1,...,x^n)$ and $m$ dependent variables $(r^1,...,r^m)$. A reparametrization is just a change of variables that represent parameters.

Let's talk about coordinates, now. When you're dealing with points in space; you call those $(x^1,...,x^n)$ the *coordinates* of a point.

A coordinate system allows you to identify every point in your space with a unique ordered set of numbers (well, you can allow some points to be labelled with more than one ordered set of numbers as long as the set of all of these numbers has $0$ $n$-dimensional volume). The change of one coordinate system to another is called a *change of coordinates*.

A change of coordinates tells you how to go from one way of labelling all points of space to another way of labelling all points in space; you can think of this as parametrizing all space instead of just a curve, surface or manifold in it. You can use a change of coordinates as a change of variables in a multiple integral, as you may already know:

$$\int{\cdots\int{f(q^1,...,q^n)}\space {\text{d}q}^1\cdots{\text{d}q}^n}=\int{\cdots\int{f(\vec{\Phi} (q^1,...,q^n))}\space\left|\frac{\partial(q^1,...,q^n)}{\partial(x^1,...,x^n)}\right| {\text{d}x}^1\cdots{\text{d}x}^n}$$

where $\vec{\Phi}(q^1,...,q^n)=(x^1,...,x^n)$ is the change of variables.

A *transformation* isn't the same as a change of variable, though. The word 'transformation' usually implies leaving things different than they were before, while change of variables implies leaving things as they are, but with a different name.

For example: a matrix can represent both a linear endomorphism (a linear transformation of a vector space) and a change of basis matrix (a matrix that takes in a vector expressed with respect to one basis and changes its coordinates to the ones with respect to another basis). Those are two different operations at a conceptual level, as one changes the areas, volumes... of your space while the other keeps everything the way it was.

In fact, a transformation need not be bijective at all, while a change of variables HAS to be bijective (again, except for a $0$ $n$-dimentional volume set of points in the most general case, definitely not in the linear case).

Comment: So you could say a 'change of variables' is a special type of transformation $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n $ that is a bijective map.

Comment: Well, both a change of variables and a transformation are represented by $\mathbb{R}^n\longmapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ functions, and it's true that a change of variables is required to be bijective(-ish), but I think it's best to differenciate between active transformations and passive transformations (this is, changes of variables).

Comment: A change of variables, @john, doesn't transform anything but the labels we give to each point. A transformation, on the contrary, does.

Comment: The most salient statement, or the statement that sums up your point, i think is here. "A change of coordinates tells you how to go from one way of labelling all points of space to another way of labelling all points in space; you can think of this as a re-parameterizing all space instead of just a curve, surface or manifold in it. " I added the re- part, (does that change anything?). This is a good way to think of a change of coordinates (change of variables?), it is a re-parameterizing or parameterizing of space, as opposed to just parameterizing a curve or surface in the space.

Comment: I was thinking of a change of coordinates as a transformation of the axes themselves (whilst keeping the points in the graph fixed). Like a scaling of the axes - though the axes are not an actual part of the graph. But i understand your point, it might be better to reserve the word transformation for mappings of points to new points.

Comment: Indeed. Us physicists usually like to say "passive transformation" when referring to a change of coordinates due to a change in the frame of reference, and imagine the axis moving instead of space itself; but the adjective "passive" there is already implying that a proper "transformation" is a mapping of points to new points, as you just said.

Comment: I am actually confused by this article, they call change in coordinates a transformation https://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/chap3/chap3-1/printversion.pdf
Also you write that a change of coordinates keeps everything the way it was, does not change area , volume 
"... as one changes the areas, volumes... of your space while the other keeps everything the way it was." But a change in variable does change area since we multiply by the jacobian , see https://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_variables_area_calculation
I think I understand what you mean though. I don't mean to pester.

Comment: When performing a coordinate transformation ---while computing a volume integral, say---, the Jacobian is not telling you by how much volumes change, it is precisely the factor that you need for volumes to stay as they were before.

Comment: If changing variables changed the volume, @john, then we would not be able to use a change of variables because it would change the quantity we aim to compute.

Comment: Wikipedia calls a change of coordinates a '[coordinate transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system#Transformations)'. It seems that you were arguing above this would be bad use of the term 'transformation', as the term transformation should be used only for active transformations. A coordinate transformation would better be called change of coordinates.
From wiki " Such relations are described by coordinate transformations which give formulas for the coordinates in one system in terms of the coordinates in another system." Students should probably be aware of the jargon.